DAX studio not showing as external tool in Power BI desktop
I installed Power BI desktop and DAX studio. DAX studio generated a file in  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Power BI Desktop\External Tools folder named daxstudio.pbitool.json with the following content:
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "DAX Studio",
  "description": "Use DAX Studio for DAX authoring, diagnosis, performance tuning and analysis.",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files\\DAX Studio\\DaxStudio.exe",
  "arguments": "/server=\"%server%\" /database=\"%database%\"",
  "iconData": "image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2Z.........SIvPjwvc3ZnPg=="
} 

When I start Power BI, I don't see an "External Tools" ribbon, and "External Tools" in the "Help" ribbon is disabled.
How to enable DAX studio as external tool in Power BI? Same problem with Tabular Editor, I installed and still cannot see an "External Tools" ribbon.

Have you tried to restart your machine?
